Converted infinite sum into integral, but not sure whether it is correct
What is the result of $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} \sin \left(\frac{n^2}{k}\right)$？
I tried the question in the above link, by converting infinite sum into indefinite integral, but not sure if it is correct or not
The original question is evaluating $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2}\sin(\frac{n^2}{k})$
So I converted this integral into the following steps
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2} \sin(\frac{n^2}{k})$
$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2} \frac{e^\frac{in^2}{k}-e^{-\frac{in^2}{k}}}{2i}$
And here's the problem
$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{1} x \frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i} dx$
Is this correct or not?
Please let me know if it is possible or not...
Besides, The result is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin n - n \cos n}{n^2}=0$
Which corresponds to the correct answer, and this made me more confusing...

I suspect you really meant $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^1 x, \frac{e^{i n x}-e^{-i n x}}{2i}, dx$$ (you had the sign wrong on the second exponent). It may be true that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2}\sin(\frac{n^2}{k})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^1 x, \frac{e^{i n x}-e^{-i n x}}{2i}, dx=0,,$$ but it may also be true that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2}\sin(\frac{n^2}{k})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^1 x, \frac{1}{n}, dx=0.$$

Also $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2}\sin(\frac{n^2}{k})\ne\int\limits_0^1 x, \frac{e^{i n x}-e^{-i n x}}{2i}, dx$$ so perhaps you need to clarify your question.

@StevenClark You explained exactly what I wanted. Thank you!
